# responsive footer that stays at the bottom

Tags: html, css, responsive

I don't know why I have so much trouble with this concept!  Basically I am creating a single page site.  My content shows / hides based on adding a class of active to the sections.  The main content section is absolute, within relative; then I have my footer.  The footer is supposed to fit neatly in the bottom.  If the user has their phone portrait view, but when they switch it to landscrape breaks. I want it to be response but I think I may need to use a media query.  Any thoughts on this?

https://jsfiddle.net/r_heneault/jt7x12jk/5/

```
#content {position:relative;height:70%;}
/*FOOTER*/
footer {position:relative;bottom:0px;padding:5vmin;height:25vmin;background-color:#f2f2f2;left:0px;right:0px;}
```

Comment: posistion:fixed maybe ?

Comment: I tried this but it appears when I scroll and its always there.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a mobile app; decided to make the footer / header sticky, set the content with padding to fit top and bottom.  I set the content section with overflow:scroll.  Looks nice.